# How can I hack this table in CSS to hide the borders on one row?

Tags: css

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="root">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>red</td>
        <td>rox</td>
        <td>blanket</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blue</td>
        <td>cat</td>
        <td>potato</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>green</td>
        <td>hamster</td>
        <td>Form1040</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And styles to apply a border around the outside:

```
.root {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Assume for the sake of argument that both the markup and the styles on `.root` (i.e., the border on the enclosing div) are fixed and cannot be changed.

I want to remove the left and right borders *on the top row only*:

[image]

By "remove" I mean "make it look ok any way we can." I'm fine with covering over the border with a white border/outline/`:before` div, etc., or any other dirty tricks.

What styles, if any, can I apply to `.row1` to achieve this?

Comment: Your question title does not reflects the actual question's image and HTML markup...

Comment: Please show your current markup and CSS. How are the borders currently applied?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
}

tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>rox</td>
      <td>blanket</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blue</td>
      <td>cat</td>
      <td>potato</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>green</td>
      <td>hamster</td>
      <td>Form1040</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have a bordered wrapper (as per your edit) than use the ::before and ::after pseudo:

```css
.root {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
}

tbody tr:first-child td:first-child::before,
tbody tr:first-child td:last-child::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
tbody tr:first-child td:first-child::before {
  left: -3px;
}

tbody tr:first-child td:last-child::before {
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>rox</td>
      <td>blanket</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blue</td>
      <td>cat</td>
      <td>potato</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>green</td>
      <td>hamster</td>
      <td>Form1040</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It turns out my border is on a div outside the table, not on the table itself, so I don't think `border-collapse` will work. I've edited the post to fix this. You absolutely answered the question as originally asked -- my sincere apologies for the bait-and-switch.

Comment: why don't you simply remove that border from .root? @Sasgorilla

Comment: ... it's complicated? I'm exploring that option too but it creates a lot of problems of its own (outside of the scope of this question). So this question specifically is to see if it's possible to work with that border.

Comment: just use ::before on the first and last td children.

Comment: I've been playing with `::before` on the `td` and `tr`, but so far I'm unable to get it to appear outside of the table itself (and thus outside of the border). `position: relative` doesn't seem to have any effect. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Sasgorilla I would have some suggestions, but first make sure to create a [mcve]. One line of CSS does not reflect much of the styles you have.

Comment: @Sasgorilla you need to set position relative to your TD, in order to place the ::before pseudo as position absolute where needed. Edited my answer.